# nat:extip with toml configuration

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I'm running the following command to get the toml configuration file:

```
geth --datadir ./chain --nat extip:182.168.1.2 dumpconfig echo > config.toml
```

But when I start get with the config.toml

```
geth --config config.toml console
```

I get the error.

```
Fatal: config.toml, line 35: (p2p.Config.NAT) cannot unmarshal TOML array into nat.Interface (need slice)
```

I think it's coming from `--nat extip:182.168.1.2`, because without it is working.

Here the relevant part of config.toml.

```
NAT = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 182, 168, 1, 2]
```

Any idea how to get past this issue ?